# possible "pkill -f node" alternative on windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, yarnpkg

I am currently trying to fix:

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

One solution was to run `pkill -f node` but that is a macOS-specific thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume "pkill" is a "process kill" command, the windows equivalent would be `taskkill -f -im "node.exe"`, assuming node.exe is the process you want to kill.

Comment: @404 The difference is that `pkill` kills any processes that contain a certain phrase. For example `pkill a` would kill all of the imaginary processes `apple`, `banana` and `carrot`.

Comment: Ok, in that case `taskkill -f -im "node*"`. Can't start with a wildcard though.

Comment: @404 when I try both of your solutions the error message "ERROR: The process "node*" not found." pops up. I have node downloaded, set up and everything. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean _fix_ it? That suggests your app has the problem, why does a process need killing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did some research and the solution was to do the above. This is because of all the running server process in the background. So all I need to do is stop them from the terminal.

Comment: It's unclear what your actual problem is, what research you did, where you found that. The message on its own just tells you the app has crashed, and nodemon will restart it once you've edited a file it's watching. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ohhh, thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use `taskkill` as suggested in the comments. Use an asterisk for a partial name of a process. For example, to kill all python scripts:

> taskkill -f -im python*

And in your case, the solution can look like:

> taskkill -f -im node*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `taskkill` accepts its options with hyphens, not just slash. I was having issues with GitBash reinterpreting `/F` as `F:/`, but `-f` works perfectly.